# Running out of unique IDs in sqlite database

Tags: database, sqlite, unique, auto-increment

I know that sqlite database automatically generates a unique id (autoincrement) for every record inserted.

Does anyone know if there is any possibility of running out of system unique IDs in sqlite3 database, while executing the replace query?

I mean that every piece of data in database has its own type. For example, system unique id is something like int. What would the database do with the next record, if it generates unique id equal to MAX_INT?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The maximum possible ID is 9223372036854775807 (2^63 - 1).  In any case, if it can't find a new auto-increment primary key, it will return SQLITE_FULL.

There is one other important point.  If you use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, it can reuse keys that were in the table earlier, but have been deleted.  If you use INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, it can never reuse an auto-increment key.

Comment: I got it. As i can see - i don't own this ROWID. As i read from the docs: if i have an integer autoincrement column, it would be an alias of ROWID of this table, and the ROWID would also be autoincrement. If i do not have autoincrement column (just a primary key integer) - the ROWID would also be just primary key integer.

But in my table i do not have any integer primary key. What type of key would be ROWID? Would it be autoincrement?

Many thanks

Comment: @msj, I believe if you don't explicitly declare any kind of INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, it will use the top algorithm [from here](http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html).  However, you can only access it through `ROWID`.

Comment: I also want to believe. Thanks for the answers.

Answer (score 8):

http://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html

"If the largest ROWID is equal to the largest possible integer (9223372036854775807) then the database engine starts picking positive candidate ROWIDs at random until it finds one that is not previously used. If no unused ROWID can be found after a reasonable number of attempts, the insert operation fails with an SQLITE_FULL error. If no negative ROWID values are inserted explicitly, then automatically generated ROWID values will always be greater than zero."

Given that sqlite ids are 64-bit you could insert a new record every 100 milliseconds for the next 546 years before running out (I made up those numbers; but you get the idea).

Comment: It's actually 2.92277266 × 10^10 years ([100 ms * 9223372036854775807 in years](https://www.google.com/search?q=100%20ms%20*%209223372036854775807%20in%20years))